# How to prevent settings.settings file reset after each new installation

Tags: c#, wpf, advanced-installer, settings.settings

So I have `WPF` `application` and I am using `settings.settings` file to save several settings for example specific `Path` that the user need to set and I am also create a `exe` installation file using `Advanced installer` and after install new `application` version all the application files (include the application `exe` file) replaced with the new version and in such case all `settings.settings` variables reset and I want to prevent it.

Any ideas ?

Comment: Don't use this mechanism. Instead, serialise a class holds user specific values to appdata. This way you can write code controls when the file is initialised etc. And you control what happens for new values when you install v3 with settings you didn't think of for v1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct, when you upgrade your application you want your settings.settings file to be saved. If you don't want to use "Side by side install", you can do this:

1. On install time, from AI, add a "New File Operation" and copy your file to an backup folder for example.
2. Now you need to copy back your file when the new application is installed. You need to add a script with custom action with sequence (Launch file for .bat, or PowerShell inline script). You can do that with .bat or PowerShell. I recommend you .bat since is more easy. Configure this custom action to be be executed "When the system is being modified (deferred)", check "Run under the LocalSystem account" and also on "Execution Stage Condition" select only "Install".
   You can find how to copy files in .bat on google, it's something with `xcopy /Y %1 %2`

If this is what you need and you can't implement it, just tell me and I will try to help you.

Comment: I don't think I understand your suggestion, Can you elaborate ?

Comment: You said you are using Advanced Installer, you can do there what I said, copy your file config when you install your new app version, and at the end of the install you copy back from backup folder your saved file.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows Forms apps I use code like this in my main form, after the call to InitializeComponent(). It copies the settings from the previous version the first time the new version runs.

```
if (Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeRunningThisVersion)
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Upgrade();
   Properties.Settings.Default.FirstTimeRunningThisVersion=false;
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
```

FirstTimeRunningThisVersion is type bool and its default value must (obviously) be True.